# Remove text on Google Map

Tags: html, google-maps

I have a created a Google map and placed it [here](http://aesdigital.co.uk/English/Contact).

The code I was given off Google to implement into this page is:

```
    <iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=z7-P7jo5tJrQ.kuOE5OBf5hc0" width="250" height="250"></iframe>
```

What I want to be able to do is remove the black header, the text on the map that says Google Maps Engine and the footer text at the bottom Map data © 2014 Google For non-commercial use, so that it looks like this:[image]

When I right click inspect element I can remove them but whereabouts in the code does this get added ?

Comment: I don't think you can as it is in an Iframe. Also, I think it would go against Googles policy to delete that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .ilErfe-yePe5c-haAclf {
        display: none; // not work add !important
    }
    #map-pane div {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
   }
```

[image]